# Como escolher (dependendo do login) qual master page executar?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017

Queria algo parecido com isto (esta não funciona).
Erro "A propriedade 'MasterPageFile' só pode ser definida no ou antes do evento 'Page_PreInit'."

```
foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
            {
                if (item["tipoLogin"].ToString().Contains("admin"))
                {

                    MasterPageFile = "~/MasterPage.master";
                    Response.Redirect("HomeAdmin.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (item["tipoLogin"].ToString().Contains("gestor"))
                    {
                        MasterPageFile = "~/MasterGestor.master";
                        Response.Redirect("HomeGestor.aspx");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (item["tipoLogin"].ToString().Contains("responsavel"))
                        {
                            MasterPageFile = "~/MasterPageResponsavel.master";
                            Response.Redirect("HomeResponsavel.aspx");
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o erro diz, para informar qual MasterPage usar, use o evento `Page_PreInit`

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //Sua Logica Aqui
    this.MasterPageFile = "~/SuaMasterPage.master"; 
}
```

Você pode ler mais sobre isso na [Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/master-pages/specifying-the-master-page-programmatically-cs)

Comment: funcionou, já estava à muito tempo de volta disto , o meu cérebro deu tilt nem prestei atenção no erro muito Obrigado !

Comment: @PedroCardoso Fico feliz em ter ajudado, não se esqueça de marcar como aceita ;) assim se outros tiverem a mesma dúvida irão ver como você resolveu o problema.